# keyboard lockup after hold ctrl key

Tags: fedora, keyboard, freeze

With Fedora 17 I have a PS/2-connected keyboard. If I hold just the left <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key down for a period (say 5 seconds) then the whole keyboard locks up. The USB-connected mouse still works and I can navigate menus, etc. I can logout and then the keyboard works for login. While locked up I cannot use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, etc., to switch to a different virtual terminal.

Anyone seen similar symptoms and/or have a clue as to the cause and/or a cure?

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the keyboard and connect it back? If you can, test the keyboard in another machine, another PS/2 keyboard on that machine, and the keyboard with a different OS, to see whether the keyboard, the motherboard or the OS is at fault.

Comment: Disconnect/reconnect of keyboard no help. I do not run other other OSs (at least not on systems with a PS/2 interface). As noted, logout is sufficient to restore operation. I can try other fault-isolation techniques but I was interested to hear if any others have similar experiences.

Comment: Does this happen under X only, only in the console, both? Can you try with another keyboard (i.e., an USB one)?

Comment: Only with X11. Not managed to try with a USB keyboard yet.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you didn't turn on `slow keys`. In this regime the keyboard actually works, but you have to press a key for about a second.

It can be turned off by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> for about 8 seconds or longer.

It can be [disabled](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~guenther/slow-keys.html) e.g. by installing xkbset and

```
xkbset -sl  # Disable slow keys (if already active).
xkbset -a   # Disable accessibility to prevent it from switching on.
```

To understand better what actually happens, read

```
tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

and maybe

```
dmesg | tail
```